# I want to log mongologs to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am writing a program to save logs from a mongodb instance to its database.

1. I have two db's, SILENT and VERBOSE
2. on mongo shell I run

> use VERBOSE
>
> db.setLogLevel(2)

Mongo will still spit logs when inserting documents to SILENT.
This will create infinite loop of logging as my program will read all logs from the instance and save them to a collection in SILENT db.

Programatically, I can solve this problem by

a) running two mongo instaces or;

b) filtering out logs from commands which write to SILENT.

I want to know if there is any solution other than a) or b).

Comment: I would definitely be cautious about feeding database logs into the same deployment you are collecting from, particularly with logLevel 2 (which will include very verbose debug messages). What is your use case for saving the full logs into a database at that level of verbosity? Enabling the [database profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) can be handy for a quick sample for performance tuning, but for detailed diagnostic investigation I would filter relevant info from the MongoDB logs and consider increasing the log level by component if appropriate.

Comment: I am leaving logs about changes made to the database updates in particular in case a history needs to be constructed in the future. The lowest level which would leave logs for CRUD commands seem to be level 2

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to implement document versioning or auditing. Do you plan to use this history to reconstruct older versions of documents or do you just need the timeline of changes? For document versioning there is a helpful series of posts on the Ask Asya blog: [How to Track Versions with MongoDB](http://www.askasya.com/post/trackversions/), [Further Thoughts on How to Track Versions with MongoDB](http://www.askasya.com/post/revisitversions/), and [Best Versions with MongoDB](http://www.askasya.com/post/bestversion/).

Comment: For basic auditing of CRUD activity you could perhaps use [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) (MongoDB 3.6+). If you have control over the applications connecting to your deployment, some ODMs or frameworks also have support for versioning and/or auditing. For more extensive auditing requirements you could consider using the [Auditing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/auditing/) capability which is available with MongoDB Enterprise or MongoDB Atlas.